# Change folder preview image via powershell?

Tags: powershell

***Hello, is there any way to change a folder preview image via powershell script?***

[image: preview image]

Comment: Please try to follow this guide when asking a question to get the best possible answer from the community, welcome! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this blog, the shortcut file can be modified by loading it as a shell object and then modifying the icon location.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-change-the-icon-for-an-existing-shortcut/

For folders use these references

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini
https://www.itdroplets.com/change-folder-icon-powershell/